# "Global name not defined" error

Tags: python, python-2.7

There are several posts around this error I have already read, but I still don't get what I am doing wrong.

I put it into a minimal example:
Imagine I have a Doc.py, and the package Tools which includes Tool1.py and Tool2.py.

Doc.py:

```py
from Tools import *
import sys

def __main__():
    TOOL_REPORT("Tool1","Test")

def TOOL_REPORT(tool, path):
    if(tool == 'Tool1'):
        Tool1.REPORT(path)
    elif(tool == 'Tool2'):
        Tool2.REPORT(path)
    else:
        sys.stderr.write("This tool is not yet included in Doc. Please check TOOLS for more information.")

if __name__=="__main__": __main__()
```

Tool1.py:

```py
def REPORT(path):
    print("Tool1 "+path)
```

Tool2.py:

```py
def REPORT(path):
    print("Tool2 "+path)
```

If I run this, I always end up with this error:

> File "Doc.py", line 15, in TOOL_REPORT
>
> Tool1.REPORT(path)
>
> NameError: global name 'Tool1' is not defined

I'd appreciate any hint to what is going wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Tool1` and `Tool2` submodules are not visible until explicitly imported *somewhere*.

You can import them in the `Tools/__init__.py` package file:

```
import Tool1, Tool2
```

at which point they become available for import from `Tools`.

Another option is to import the modules from your own code:

```
import Tools.Tool1, Tools.Tool2
from Tools import *
```

Only when explicitly imported are submodules also set as attributes of the package.

Comment: Thank you, importing them to the __init__ file did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Python will treat any folder as a module when there is `__init__.py` file present in it. Otherwise it will just be another folder for python and not a module from which it can import things. So just add **init**.py file in your Tool folder (so it will become module in pythonic terms) and then you can import that module in other python scripts.

One more things for better practice instead of using

```
from Tools import *
```

Always provide the file name of library specifically which you want to import like in your case you should use it like this

```
from Tools import Tool1, Tool2
```

This will enhance the code readbility for others and for you too.